# Not able to connect Github repository with local git-bash on personal laptop

Tags: git, azure, github, ssh, azure-active-directory

I am no longer able to connect to my github respository account using my personal laptop.
It gives below error:

```
$ git push -u origin main
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I checked my ssh config. Tried adding my public key to github - it says keys are already in use.

May be I messed up my git-local by trying something new for azure authentication because when I ran git config --list, following 2 lines seems to be suspicious as why credential has to be azure something as I am not using any azure authentication. I am not using any VPN or Proxy as its my personal laptop. How do I correct the setting to make it normal as when it's setup. Or where else can be the problem? What should I check?

```
credential.helper=manager-core
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
```

Full config listing is below:

```
$ git config --list
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
pull.rebase=false
credential.helper=manager-core
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
init.defaultbranch=master
user.name=My name
user.email=myEmail@email.com
core.longpaths=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
alias.st=status
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:myusername/myAppApp.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: The error message looks like the `PAT` (Personal Access Token) is expired. Kindly check the `PAT` token by navigating to **Profile > Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Tokens > Token**  [Here](https://i.imgur.com/r1nTgDc.png), if **PAT Token** expired kindly generate new token and check the same.

Comment: @JimRedmond Windows 10 Pro

Comment: @nanosoft , Have you verified your **PAT** token in the **Git repository**?

Comment: @VenkatV Iam not developing/building API or extending Github. So that's not applicable for me.

Comment: credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true ---> Is this line normal ?

Comment: @nanosoft , if PAT Token expire, you are unable to authenticate your **Git Repository**, the **Error** message you are getting related to PAT token expire, for testing create another repository and try to push files using Git bash.

Comment: Configure your Git identity with your name and email address if you haven't already done so. Replace "Your Name" and "youremail@example.com" with your actual information: git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "youremail@example.com" and Check the Status  : git status

Comment: @VenkatV - Git identity is properly configured and PAT token is not applicable in my case as I am not developing/buiding API extending/using github APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I don't understand what was wrong. May be my local ssh key got corrupted or updated by mistake.

What worked is:

```
 - Delete old ssh key in my laptop.
 - Generate new key.
 - Configure that in Github
```